# "SQL Server doesn't exist or access denied" while importing Excel sheet into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to import an Excel sheet into SQL Server using C#.
This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    of1.Filter = "xls|*.xlsx";
    if ((of1.ShowDialog()) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        imagepath = of1.FileName; //image path
        textBox1.Text = imagepath.ToString();
    }
}

private void loadbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ssqltable = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    string myexceldataquery = "select * from ["+ ssqltable + "$]";
    try
    {
        string sexcelconnectionstring = @"Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security = SSPI; Persist Security Info = True; Data Source = AMR - PC; Use Procedure for Prepare = 1; Auto Translate = True; Packet Size = 4096; Workstation ID = AMR - PC; Use Encryption for Data = False; Tag with column collation when possible = False; Initial Catalog = BioxcellDB";
        string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bioxcell;Integrated Security=True";
        OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
        OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
        oledbconn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
        }

        oledbconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

A message box shows this error:

> 0x80004005 [DBNETLIB]SQL Server doesn't exist or access denied

Then I tried to check my connection string in another project and worked fine.

Where is the problem? .. Sorry for bad English

Comment: Can you post stack trace of this error ?

Comment: The error is on Line : ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bioxcell;Integrated Security=True";  DataSource is wrong.  See connection strings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: i used the same datasource in another application and works fine

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/IXA2D this is the full message

Comment: i tried to change excel connection string and made it 
                string sexcelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Work\Bioxcell\UCB.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
error changed to .. provider is not registerd on local machine

Comment: What is the target platform of your project (AnyCPU, x86 or x64)? Have you tried changing it (to x86 or x64)? This might help in the case that the target platform of your project is different to the platform of the installed ACE.OLEDB driver (i.e. your application runs as x64, but the installed ACE.OLEDB driver is x86)

Comment: AnyCPU .. I tried to change to x86 but the same error message

Comment: My office version is 2013 and excel sheet extension is xlsx

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: i downloaded it but nothing changed